# variables retrieved from a form using post dropping off characters after the first space

Tags: php, html

I have been looking around online for similar issues and I'm sure it has been answered before but nothing I've read has made sense to me on this.

I have a html form with text input fields i want the user to complete. When they submit the form it posts the value to the next page to be used later. The problem i have is if the input has a space in then everything after that space gets dropped off the variable and I don't understand why.
Here is my code:

```
<form action="user_lookup.php" method="post" class="form">
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="jbloggs">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In my next page i have the following line to grab the user inputted value and then i am displaying this variable in another form:

```
$username = $_POST["userName"]

<form action="create.php" method="post" class="form">
<label>UserID:</label><input  type="text" name="userid" value=<?php echo "$username" ?> >
```

For example if i input the username as "Joe Bloggs" in the next page where i display the variable as text it will only show "Joe"

My question is how to i make sure the entire string is used for the variable not just everything up to the first space?

Comment: at first look i dont see any issue with this code but on your "NEXT PAGE" you can check where $_POST["userName"] come from and debug it to see what is the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the "" around php worked for me:
`value="<?php echo $username ?>"`

Answer (score 2):

This line here in your second page is the problem:

```
<input  type="text" name="userid" value=<?php echo "$username" ?> >
```

What it produces looks like this:

```
<input  type="text" name="userid" value=Joe Bloggs>
```

The inner quotes of your `echo` are interpreted as string quotes, and therefore not echoed. Fix it like this by adding quotes around the PHP tag:

```
<input  type="text" name="userid" value="<?php echo "$username" ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

i got the issue ,

which is in

```
<input type="text" name="userid" value=<?php echo "$username" ?> >
```

this should be

```
<input type="text" name="userid" value="<?php echo "$username" ?>" >
```

try to copy below code

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="jbloggs">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php

$username = $_POST["userName"];

?>

<form action="create.php" method="post" class="form">
<label>UserID:</label>
<input type="text" name="userid" value="<?php echo "$username" ?>" >
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks